# Stripe payment interval

Tags: angular, stripe-payments, angular2-services

I am using Angular 2 application. I have integrated stripe payment in it which is working fine, but i want the payment should be done periodically once the user have register his card details in stripe.

> Example : If User have purchased for some product and paid for next 1
>   year by registering his card details, then next year it should not ask
>   for the card details and it should automatically(for next one year) do
>   the payment.

Please guide me through it.

**PS : Need on stripe.**

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [Stripe Subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quickstart) for that.

Comment: I have tried with stripe plans and subscriptions, but it doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: You could also just use the Token to create a Customer instead of a Charge, and then create the Charge using the Customer - and then you can repeat that on your end as often as necessary.

https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards